# Hovering color of Kendo grid panel

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

```
<kendo-panelbar class="mb-4">
    <kendo-panelbar-item [title]="null">
      <ng-template kendoPanelBarItemTitle>
        <h4 class="d-inlin">
          Details
        </h4>
</ng-template>
</kendo-panelbar-item>
  </kendo-panelbar>
```

I have a kendo panel bar whose background is blue and on highligh the color changes to reddish color.
How can I make sure that even on hovering the color stays blue

I tried implementing viewencapsulation, but it changed the background from blue to red.So both hover and background are
red.But I need both in blue.How can I modify this?
The below css classes are used to change background.But I need something to change the hovering color

```
.k-panelbar > .k-item > .k-link.k-state-selected {
  background-color : #ff6358;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.k-panelbar > .k-item > .k-link.k-state-selected {
  background-color : #0000ff;
}

.k-panelbar > .k-item > .k-link.k-state-selected:hover {
  background-color : #0000ff;
}
```

Does this do the trick for you? If something is still trumping your css, you can add !important but you should try to do this only if you have to.